# React.useEffect is not trigger when select a value from DropDownPicker in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

i have 2 select boxes and those boxes have initial value and there are button which call Add.when i press add button 2 more select box getting rendered and we need to select 1 values from each boxes and those values and initial values are push to new array.when i press submit button those new and initial values need to save with other form values.but its not.reason is i implement useEffect for push new selection box related values, when i select new rendered selection box value that useEffect need to be trigger but its only triggered when we initially loading the page.

i have tried by using multiple useEffect and debugging the code but i have't found any issue.is there are have any reason to this type of issues.

```
 <Controller
     control={control}
     name='brokerage'
     render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
       <DropDownPicker
            listMode="MODAL"
            searchable={true}
            style={styles.dropdown}
            placeholder="Select your brokerage"
            placeholderStyle={[
            styles.label,
               {
                 color: "grey",
                 fontWeight: "200",
                },
                ]}
             open={openBrokerage}
             setOpen={() => setOpenBrokerage(!openBrokerage)}
             items={itemsBrokerage}
             value={value}
             onChangeValue={(e) => {
                 brokerOnchange(e);
             }}
             setValue={(item) => { onChange(item) }}
             />
             )}
             rules={{
                    required: {
                      value: true,
                      message: 'Please fill out all required fields.'
                        }
                  }}
        />
```

```
    const updatedMarketBrokerageData: any[] = [];
    React.useEffect(() => {
       if (selectedUser) {
           let marketSelected: any = [];
           if (selectedUser?.markets && 
              selectedUser?.markets.length>0) {
                selectedUser?.markets.map((item: any) => {
                marketSelected.push(item.id);
               });
               setValueMarket(marketSelected);
      }
      if (selectedUser &&selectedUser.brokerages &&
        selectedUser.brokerages.length > 0) {
        selectedUser.brokerages &&
          selectedUser.brokerages.map((brokerage: any) => {
            updatedMarketBrokerageData && 
                  updatedMarketBrokerageData.push({
              market: brokerage.market_id,
              brokerage: brokerage.id
            });
          });
        setInitialState(updatedMarketBrokerageData);
      }
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).